# DataVisualisation Donut Chart slice clicked event

Tags: c#, winforms, charts, data-visualization

I am developing a `winforms` application with `c#`.

I have used `System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualisation.Chart` components for `Donut Chart`.

I have one requirement where if user clicks on any slice in donut chart i need to perform something.

I have checked documentation of chart component but did not find any such event.

Please let me know if my question is not clear.

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subscribe to the chart click event. In this event you can do a Hit Test Result which will point you to the chart element that was clicked. You can use this Hit Test Result to then write your code logic.

Your code within the chart click event would be as below.

```
private void chart1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HitTestResult results = chart1.HitTest((e as MouseEventArgs).X, (e as MouseEventArgs).Y);
}
```

[image: Results in the Watch]

As you can see in the debugger, you get the DataPoint that was clicked.